# iOS Calendar Access Permission Dialog, force it to appear?

Tags: ios, calendar, ios6, ios-permissions

I've written an app that requests access to the iPad's calendar. Under iOS 6, a system dialog appears that asks the user if that's okay.

Problem is, I can't replicate that situation once it's happened. For testing purposes, I want to force that dialog to come up consistently. Instead, the OS caches previous settings and doesn't bring up the dialog again. This is still the case even if I delete the app off the iPad and re-install. (Changing the app name and bundle fixes the problem, but I don't want to do that every time I test.)

Does anyone know how to force this to appear?

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ask for permission to access iphone contacts adressbook again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478053/how-to-ask-for-permission-to-access-iphone-contacts-adressbook-again)

Comment: @QED : The question you mention is asked 7 months after (May 2013) this question , so how can this question be duplicate of that ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks for answering your own question, this a great q+a for people.

Comment: Worked for me on iOS 8.1.2

Answer (score 1):

You can *Reset Location and Privacy* as suggested by Greg Maletic but if you do not want to reset all your apps, you can just change the bundle identifier of your app.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 9 and later version,uninstall and install the app,access permission dialog will appeared.
But iOS 8 will remember what you choose.

Answer (score 0):

On **iOS 10.2.1**:

I simply uninstall and reinstall the app again, the permission dialog appeared again.