# Testing permissions for microphone / push in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-permissions

Usually, I was able to test different flows for mic / push permission on iOS by deleting the app and then launching again from XCode. However, recently I am unable to do so because even after deleting the app, when I relaunch the app, instead of asking for permission, it somehow brings back the permissions that I had given to the deleted app. This means it is impossible for me to test alternate flows for asking permission. Has anyone else faced this problem? Can someone guide me to getting back to being asked for permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Calendar Access Permission Dialog, force it to appear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635288/ios-calendar-access-permission-dialog-force-it-to-appear)

Comment: That duplicate applies to all of the privacy permissions, not just calendar.