# force ios app to request permission again

Tags: ios, permissions, notifications, push-notification

I need my app to request notification permission again.  I have tried to reinstall the app.  I have also tried to reset the privacy settings (Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy) per this post: [iOS Calendar Access Permission Dialog, force it to appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635288/ios-calendar-access-permission-dialog-force-it-to-appear).  I tried reinstalling after doing so.  Nothing I have done makes any difference.  It seems that this may have changed in iOS8.  Is there a way to force a permission request in iOS8?

Comment: Late... but this solution is much easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635288/ios-calendar-access-permission-dialog-force-it-to-appear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's described in [TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2265/_index.html):

1. Delete your app from the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

Comment: Do I reinstall after step 4? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Yes of course. It's important that you don't miss a step, even if it's a pain to reboot your device two times, but it's necessary.